# How to see the comment of a zip archive in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Zip applications allow user to add comments. For example WinZip or WinRAR has an option to add comments to the zip archive, and when we open it the comment is either popped up or is shown in the right pane.

I have uploaded zip files to Google Drive. I couldn't find the option to view the comments stored in a zip archive. Maybe Google Drive does not have that option at present.

Is there any way to see the comment saved in a zip archive?